# How to bind delegated events within JavaScript for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, events, for-loop, bind

I have an array of objects that I am looping over using a standard JavaScript for-loop. I am trying to use jQuery to create delegated events for each one of these objects while in the loop. Each object has an `eventType` property, which can be any custom event, and also an `el` property, which is a string representing the CSS selector for an element. The point of using delegated events is that I want to bind the events to the `body` or `document` such that if an element doesn't exist in the DOM yet, it will still get get the proper event handler. Some pseudocode below:

```
// Fn that does the looping (all of this in large prototype definition)
trackAll: function(callback) {
  for (var i = 0, l = this.dataSet.length; i < l; i++) {
        var current_object = this.dataSet[i];
        // Validate properties first (check for errors)
        this.propertyCheck(current_object);
        // Then run the tracking
        if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
            this.autoTracker(current_object, callback);
        } else {
            this.autoTracker(current_object);
        } 
    }
}
```

In the above, `dataSet` is the array of objects. Each object has a footprint like this:

```
{
    trackType: 'event',
    el: '.some_class li > a',
    page: 'Homepage',
    type: 'Custom description',
    label: window.location.href,
    eventType: 'click',
    bodyClass: null,
    row: null
}
```

So this particular object refers to a particular anchor link as its element with a `trackType` of 'event' and an `eventType` of 'click'

Ultimately, there would be scores of these objects in the `dataSet` array, and I am trying to loop through and create event listeners/handlers for each. Here's a bit more pseudocode that handles this:

```
autoTracker: function(config, callback) {
    var self = this;
    if (config.el !== null && config.el !== 'undefined') {
        config.el = $(config.el); 
        if (config.trackType.toLowerCase() === 'event' || config.trackType.toLowerCase() === 'pageview') { 
            $(document).on(config.eventType, config.el, function(e) {
                console.log('fired!'); //=> this fires for ALL items in the array on ONE single click (or whatever eventType)
            });
            if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback.apply(config); //=> keep reference to `config` object in callback 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

So, the above function gets called for each object in the `dataSet` array within the loop that can be seen in the `trackAll` function (which calls this `autoTracker` function). The problem is that whatever is run in the handler callback for the `$(document).on(config.eventType, config.el, function(e) { ... });` gets run for every item in the array immediately. In other words, clicking on the `body` for example will trigger the handler for EVERY object in the array at once.

How can I properly create delegated events with the events bound to the `body` or `document` within a loop such that it won't fire every single event at once? I feel like there is a variable scoping issue, and I was able to successfully create and bind events within the loop using a closure and `.bind()` but this only binds the events DIRECTLY to the elements, so the elements MUST exist when the function runs. This is not what I'm trying to do. I need to use delegated events so that if the elements don't exist in the DOM right away, they can still get the events/handlers. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second arg to .on() should be a string, not a jquery object.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

A couple comments:

Changing the type of a property, like `config.el = $(config.el);` makes code difficult to reason about.

Also, this all seems rather circuitous. A more common pattern is to put semantic class names on the elements that need event handlers, when you create them. Like `<a class=clickable>`, then do `.on(click, '.clickable')`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed passing in a string instead of an object. Whoops. Also, I'm not creating any elements in this script nor can I modify them. The script only reads an array of objects and attempts to run GA tracking methods on elements in the DOM based on properties of the objects. In any case, this simple fix worked.